My generic class seems to not be *that* generic
I am currently creating a small plant caring game (Unity Engine 2022.3.40f1). It's properties (genes) are passed onto it's parts as a genome. These properties can be floats, integers or colors.
For that purpose I have created an abstract Gene<T> class (see below) from which GeneFloat : Gene<float>, GeneInt : Gene<int> are created...
And I've run into a problem: this Gene class does not seem to be as generic as I would like it to be.
The Gene<T> class
public abstract class Gene<T> {
    public abstract T value { get; set; }
    public abstract T randomRange { get; set; }
}

Example of an inherited Gene (here GeneFloat) :
public class GeneFloat : Gene<float> {
    public override float value { get; set; }
    public override float randomRange { get; set; }
}

However, I can't seem to use the Gene class as a generic! That's my problem.
The following code makes Unity log an error message into the console saying : "the generic type 'Gene<T>' requires 1 type arguments"
public struct Genome {
    public Gene[] genes; // <- a message for this line
    
    public Gene GetGeneNyName(string name) { // <- and for this one
        foreach(Gene gene in this.genes) { // <- but not for this one ?????
            if (gene.GetName() == name) return gene;
        }

        Debug.LogError($"It seems that the gene '{name}' couldn't be found in the genome. Maybe it does not exist or the spelling is wrong.");
    }
}

Could you help me figure out what is wrong?
Honestly I didn't try everything as I'm just a casual programmer and it's my first time using generics this thoroughly. I searched for some ideas on here, but nothing seems to pop out and helping me figure out.
I tried replacing Gene by Gene<int, float, Color> but, obviously, that didn't get me far.

Suppose you were to call GetGeneByName and it returns a Gene, there is nothing useful you can do with it! Both of its members value and randomRange are of type T, and we know nothing about T. How do you intend on using GetGeneByName?

I use the genes to generate the plants. I will use this method to fetch a specific gene during the generation processes (eg. genom.GetGeneByName("leafWidth")). Thus I will only use this method on known genes and of known types.
However I would like to not make a specific method for each type (like GetGeneIntByName, GetGeneFloatByName, as it is kind of stupid, and don't really help me understand)

Could'nt I use it juste like that : GeneFloat gene = genome.GetGeneByName("leafWidth"); ? It seems intuitive, I don't know

In that case why not just declare each gene as a property/field? e.g. public GeneFloat LeafWidth { get; set; }

After each section of plant genes are transmitted to the childrens and the genome is mutated. In order to do that, I need to call gene.Mutate() on each of my genes.
The problem is that they are so many that, doing that for each and everyone of them, would probably consume like 300 lines. And, would ask me to add this line for each gene I would add.
That's why I stored them in an array of genes, to iterate through them all and just call Mutate() on them without the need to worry about it

Also, mutations require a struct copy wich I only can do in the case of genes being an array. Without that, it would require a 300 paramters constructor of Genome

You need a base class which is not generic and which contains all the members having a concrete type:
public abstract class Gene
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract void Mutate();
}

This class can be used for a gene collection.
Now, derive a generic class adding the values:
public abstract class Gene<T> : Gene
{
    public virtual T Value { get; set; }
    public virtual T RandomRange { get; set; }
}

Then create the concrete classes
public class GeneFloat : Gene<float>
{
    // You can override the virtual members or leave them as is.
}

public class GeneColor : Gene<Color>
{
    // You can override the virtual members or leave them as is.
}

...

Now, you can use a type pattern to do things with concrete types
public Gene[] genes;
...
var gene = genes.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == "leafColor");
if (gene is GeneColor c) {
    Color color = c.Value;
    ...
}


I recently made something like this where the range was given by a Min value plus a Range. The random part was given by a Fraction value (between 0 and 1) and the value itself by (for float as an example):
public float Value => Min + Fraction * Range;

You can see my real implementation and use-case in my github repo GeneticCars.

You can combine the ideas of having an array of genes for easier mutation and having properties for individual genes:
public class Genome
{
    public Gene[] Genes { get; }

    public GeneFloat LeafWidth => (GeneFloat)Genes[4];
    // or, alternatively, return the value directly
    public float LeafWidth => ((GeneFloat)Genes[4]).Value;
    ...
}


I also noted that you are using a method named GetName. You might be used from Java to access fields through Get... and Set... methods for encapsulation. C# has a dedicated syntax for this purpose. I explain it in great detail in my answer to How can I find a specific element in a List?
